# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
**HTML Binding**
{{total() | currency: 'R$ ' : 2 }}


**Função**
$scope.total = function(){
        for (var i = $scope.custos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            total += $scope.custos[i].valor+total;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Qual o problema com este código?

```
ERRO
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Scope.o.total (all.min.js:1)
at fn0 (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), <anonymous>:4:473)
at expressionInputWatch (angular.js:15946)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17515)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
at done (angular.js:11831)
at completeRequest (angular.js:12033)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11966)
```

Comment: Faça `console.log($scope.custos);` e veja o que lhe aparece na consola, aposto que vai dar `undefined` :P. O problema vem daí

Comment: A variavel `custos`nao foi inicializada, posta o trecho onde voce define ela. por exemplo se fizer só isso: `$scope.custos;`vai dar esse erro, ou se o valor vier de uma função, verifica se não esta retornando `undefined`

Comment: Tem razão eu não iniciei a variável corretamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Você deve inicializar uma variável dentro do escopo em que ela é utilizada:

`$scope.custos = [];`